# Trouble converting from sRGB to CIE 1931 XYZ

Tags: color, color-theory, color-conversion, rgb, color-spaces

No idea if this is the right place to ask this, if not, please point me in a better direction.

I am trying to convert sRGB values R:100 G:78 B:94 to XYZ using this site: https://www.nixsensor.com/free-color-converter/ and get the result: 0.1009 0.0898 0.0891. These are my [settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/le27S.png)

However when I use this site to plot the XY values: https://company235.com/tools/colour/cie.html I get this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQyYQ.png). As you can see, the coordinates are outside the CIE colour space.

This doesn't make any sense to me as I am converting the sRGB values to XYZ ones, and the sRGB gamut lies entirely [inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IodXL.png) the CIE 1931 XYZ colour space.

I've also used a number of other sites to both convert sRGB to XYZ as well as plot the XYZ values and I get the same result.

Can someone help explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @user287001 Yeah that was one of the sites I tried, still getting the same result. Thanks though.

Comment: @user287001 Sorry, when I say I'm getting the same result I mean the values I input are still outside the CIE colour space, I've tried a variety of calculators and the answers for most of them are inconsistent so I think the issue lies somewhere with the calculators or with what I am doing.

Comment: @user287001 You are right, thanks, I'm dumb. I had to add up the xyz values, then divide the x and y values by the total of the xyz, then input those values and I get the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed my comments and recompiled them to an answer.

First: Your RGB(100,78,94) gives different to CIELAB XYZ 1931 conversion result depending on what light is considered to be the full white.

If we use standard illuminant D50 as our white reference, we get the same XYZ results as you with several online calculators.  This calculator is handy, because it calculates at the same time many conversions: http://www.brucelindbloom.com/ColorCalculator.html RGB numbers must be given as scaled to 0...1 i.e. values 0...255 must be divided by 255.

Your "out of the range"- result (see NOTE1) is a trivial error. You tried to use CIELAB 1931 X and Y numbers as inputs to the xy chromaticity diagram. Input values (small) x and (small) y to the diagram must be normalized i.e. X and Y values must be divided by X+Y+Z, as you can easily find for ex. from this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space

NOTE1: Being outside the flatiron area means the numbers do not present a color created by light.

Comment: Thanks again, dunno how I missed the fact I had to normalize it, I thought the Z value was something different. Also you are right about the illuminant, I haven't messed around with it much but I think D65 gives the most accurate results in regards to sRGB.